# Using scoped slots data in component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuejs-slots

I'm trying to access the scoped slots data passed from the child in the slot parent. There are numerous examples on how to do that in the template code (https://vuejs.org/guide/components/slots.html#scoped-slots), but how would one access the data in the actual component code (`<script>`)?

```
<!-- <MyComponent> template -->
<div>
  <slot :text="greetingMessage" :count="1"></slot>
</div>
```

```
<template>
<MyComponent v-slot="slotProps">
  {{ slotProps.text }} {{ slotProps.count }}
</MyComponent>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  // how can `slotProps` be accessed here?
}
</script>
```

Comment: they can't be accessed in the script.  if the parent needs the slot props to somehow change you would normally use a prop and the child would update the slot props based on that.  can you explain what you're trying to do with the slotProps? there is probably a way to do what you want without accessing the slotProps directly in your script

Comment: I'm trying to call a function of the child (where <slot> is defined) to signal a completion of some sort.

Comment: Can you give more details and show more code?  What function?  When are you trying to call it exactly?  Based on what condition?  How is it related to the slotProp?